# [variable].onclick = function () not executing, no errors in console

Tags: javascript, css, simplemodal

I'm a total novice to javascript, and this is probably very simple. I'm trying to create code where when I click on an image, the same image will launch in a modal. This is for a portfolio where it is useful to see the full size of images. I have no errors in my javascript console, but when I click the image nothing happens.

javascript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var srcImg = document.getElementsByClassName("showFull");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
srcImg.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

  var exit = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  exit.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };
```

html:

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
                <img class="slide showFull" src="images/mikesHarder.jpg alt="caption 123" style="width:100%" />
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
                <img class="slide showFull" src="images/Going-Green.jpg" alt="caption 123" style="width:100%" />
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

                      <!-- The Close Button -->
                      <span class="close">&times;</span>

                      <!-- Modal Content -->
                      <img id="img01" class="modal-content"/>
                      <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.showFull {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.showFull:hover {opacity: 0.9;}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    padding-top: 100px; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 480px;
}

.modal-content { 
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` return an array , loop throught it and add the `onclick` like : `srcImg.forEach(e => { e.onclick = function () {  ... } } );`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list - collection of elements. You need to loop/iterate through the collection. **Also**  one of your image `img` tags needs fixing. `src="images/mikesHarder.jpg alt="caption 123"` Missing a double quote at the end of the `src` which will make the other attributes invalid.

Comment: fixed img tag issue, then will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think 1 problem is that srcImg is an array of html elements and not a single element so when u write srcImg.onclick it doesn't work because you can use onclick only for DOM's object that represents an html element.

Comment: @Supuhstar now that it has been edited, sure. Before, half of it was asking for someone else to chip it, which is much better suited as a comment. Thanks Stefania for editing the above - perhaps consider adding a code example of what you mean to further improve this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function imgClick(){
        var target = event.target;
        if(target.tagName !== "IMG"){ return }
        target.src
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = target.src;
        modalImg.alt = target.alt;
        captionText.innerHTML = target.alt;
    }
```

```html
<div onclick="imgClick()">
    <img src="./11.png" alt="111" >
</div>
```

srcImg is an array, onclick should be used like this element.onclick = function(){...}